# Cannot unmount handy drive

Tags: linux, mount

HP 210 Mini
    Fedora 14 xfce
    2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64

I have inserted my handy drive. However, when I right click and select unmount I get the following message:

```
An application is preventing the volume "New Volume" from being unmounted
```

So I try from the command line:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

And I get the following message:

```
umount: /media/New Volume: device is busy.
```

All I have done is copied some files to my handy drive. So I am not sure what process is keeping my handy drive busy.

Is there any command that I can use to see what process of anything else is using the handy drive?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `lsof | grep '/media/New Volume'

You will know what file is still open.